# try run install php-xml get error

Tags: centos6

centos 6.5 yum php 5.5.35 I run `yum install php-xml`

Get the error message：

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.nwsuaf.edu.cn
 * epel: mirrors.opencas.cn
 * extras: mirrors.pubyun.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: mirrors.pubyun.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 for package: php-xml-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-xml-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
           Installed: php-common-5.5.35-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.35-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
php5-xmlreader-5.5.14-38.1.x86_64 has missing requires of php5 = ('0', '5.5.14', None)
php5-xmlreader-5.5.14-38.1.x86_64 has missing requires of php5-dom = ('0', '5.5.14', None)`

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: Don't know where php5-xmlreader comes from, but you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.5.35 is installed from "remi-php55" which is not enabled by default, so you need to enable it to get correct version of php-xml.

See the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Either:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php55 install php-xml
```

Or better (to avoid future issues, and get updates)

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php55
yum install php-xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much!According to your method.I installed it to succeed